# Initializing AVAudioPlayer to be used in more than one function

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, avaudioplayer

Usual `AVAudioPlayer` tutorials online creates a `AVAudioPlayer` within a function to where the play and stop functions of the `AVAudioPlayer` object aren't available to the object directly from other functions.  The problem is that I would like another function to stop the sound from the `AVAudioPlayer`.  This seems pretty simple by initializing the objects at the top of the class in hopes it would be accessible however in `Swift3` the `init` function for `AVAudioPlayer` includes a `throw` and a parameter for the sound file.  Swift doesn't allow us to use an instance member within a property initializer so I'm stuck on my thought process of how this could be written.

The only error I'm running into at this point is not being allowed to use an instance member in the property initializer when creating "backgroundMusicPlayer":

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class MadLibOneViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var thePlace: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var theVerb: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var theNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var theTemplate: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var theStory: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var generateStoryButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var proceedToNextMadLib: UIButton!
    //var backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    var error:NSError?

    var path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "bensound-cute", ofType: "mp3")

    var url: NSURL {
        return NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    }

    var backgroundMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url as URL, error: &error)





    @IBAction func createStory(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        theStory.text=theTemplate.text
    theStory.text=theStory.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "<place>", with: thePlace.text!)
        theStory.text=theStory.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "<verb>", with: theVerb.text!)
        theStory.text=theStory.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "<number>", with: theNumber.text!)

        generateStoryButton.isHidden=true
        proceedToNextMadLib.isHidden=false

    }

    @IBAction func showNextStory(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        view.backgroundColor=UIColor.green

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let resultViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MadLibTwoViewController") as! MadLibTwoViewController
        self.present(resultViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

    }

    @IBAction func hideKeyboard(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        thePlace.resignFirstResponder()
        theVerb.resignFirstResponder()
        theNumber.resignFirstResponder()
        theTemplate.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        proceedToNextMadLib.isHidden=true
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.theVerb.delegate = self
        self.thePlace.delegate = self
        self.theNumber.delegate = self

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Lazy initialisation/instantiation` for that. In your case this is all you need to do.

```
lazy var player: AVAudioPlayer = {
    [unowned self] in
    do {
        return try AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: self.url)
    }
    catch {
        return AVAudioPlayer.init()
    }

}()
```

For more about `Lazy Initialisation` [this](http://mikebuss.com/2014/06/22/lazy-initialization-swift/) is a good read. The interesting thing in your case is that the initialiser `throws`. I think [this forum discussion](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14464) is helpful to have a slight idea.

Comment: This compiles, much much appreciative!! I made an attempt using lazy but didn't understand how to make it work since init throws.  Can I ask, in what context are you using the word 'interesting'?  From my minor experience, I believe making the init function that throws complicates things for noobs like myself but is there a reason more seasoned developers such as yourself would prefer this or find it 'interesting'?  @Adeel

Comment: Haha! It's not about preferences @user6510422 to use an initialiser that throws. It just happened to be so in this case. It was interesting for me because it was a bit challenging. And it comes down to the attitude rather that being newbie or seasoned one. You must have heard the saying that "Every master was once a beginner". Once I was a beginner too.